# I have google cloud translation api key but still it is show me Response [403] - 355 bytes

Tags: swift

I am using RoGoogleTranslate and also using billing account Google translate API key but still it is not working i was download demo from github

Comment: https://github.com/prine/ROGoogleTranslate

Comment: Please check your Google API Account. Google recently changed the policies of the Translation API and you have to add a credit card, otherwise, you will receive a 403 Error.

Comment: I known that i have billing account for Google translation cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Try this "POST" method function -

```
open func translateTest(params: GoogleAITranslateParams, targetLanguage: String, callback:@escaping (_ translatedText:String) -> ()) {

    guard apiKey != "" else {
        return
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=\(self.apiKey)")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

        let jsonRequest = [
            "q": params.text,
            "source": "en",
            "target": targetLanguage,
            "format": "text"
            ] as [String : Any]

        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonRequest, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            let task: URLSessionDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Something went wrong: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                    return
                }

                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

                    guard httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                        if let data = data {
                            print("Response [\(httpResponse.statusCode)] - \(data)")
                        }
                        return
                    }

                    do {
                        if let data = data {
                            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                                if let jsonData = json["data"] as? [String : Any] {
                                    if let translations = jsonData["translations"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                                        if let translation = translations.first as? [String : Any] {
                                            if let translatedText = translation["translatedText"] as? String {
                                                callback(translatedText)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Serialization failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
}
```